# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1. Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to run a net core 2.1 project in Visual Studio 2017

I was installing sdk 2.1, but I still get this error.

```
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target
 `.NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core` 2.1.
```

It just appears to me, net core 1.1
It just appears to me, net core 1.1

[image]
[image]

**dotnet --info**

```
SDK de .NET Core (reflejando cualquier global.json):
 Version:   3.1.201
 Commit:    b1768b4ae7

Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.3
  Commit:  4a9f85e9f8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.513 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Looks like an ancient version of VS2017. My guess is while you have the actual SDKs installed on your system, VS doesn't know anything about them.

Comment: As everyone should be using .NET Core 3.1 today, Visual Studio 2019 Community edition is the one you should turn to. VS2017 Community does not give you an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that they have two different versions of the SDK depending on the version of visual studio you're using.

I'ts 2020 ! You should be doing .Net core 3.1 on Visual Studio 2019 !! (for new projects ;)

If not interested on updating, just download the appropiate version for VS2017, I guess you downloaded the 2019 as its the one that the MS site offers to download by default.

[All versions download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I already downloaded the sdk 2.1 for the two architectures for the VS 2017 and it still does not appear,

Comment: After taking a look at the list of SDKs installed, looks like you have installed versions for both VS2017 and VS2019, I would try to open and compile the project with VS2019 if that's the case. (Even if you started the project with VS2017) Also on a side note, x86 versions are included on x64 versions so there's no need for them, if you're on a x64 machine.

Comment: Yes, so far with vs 2019 it has run normally, but I still do not understand why the problem in vs 2017

Comment: I don't know, I guess that is somehow getting the wrong binary but, What's the point on using the old version?